# Does aws cognito support getting info like email from identity providers like Facebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito

Oauth explicitly allows to ask for additional information from identity providers using 'scopes'.

Does AWS cognito support retrieving and storing info from additional oauth scopes in a cognito profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito federated identities only explicitly supports leveraging logins from public providers like Facebook to get AWS credentials, so no, it will not support getting info like that.

That being said, it should still be possible, but would require a hook built on the login that lives entirely inside your code.